# Cast NSNumber as a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS development so this is probably a stupid question, I want to display an NSNumber in a label on a viewcontroller how do I cast it as a string so it will work? Here is the line of code:

cell.textLabel.text = videos.videoID;  // videoID is an NSNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:videos.videoID numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
```

Comment: Thank you, coming from C# you take those easy casts for granted. in c# it's just .ToString();

Comment: @SamCromer Calling a method like ToString() isn't a cast, at least not in the standard C definition of the word "cast".

Comment: true but it does give you a string.... ok how about int.parse....

Answer (score 1):

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [NSNumberFormatter new];
cell.textLabel.text = [nf stringFromNumber:videos.videoID]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.textLabel.text = videos.videoID.stringValue;
```